# Attempt to upload to pre-signed URL generated by Java SDK leads to AuthorizationQueryParametersError

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 via pre-signed URL generated by Java client but I'm getting

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
    <Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'ca-central-1'</Message>
    <Region>ca-central-1</Region>
    <RequestId>G5WQRR38PQVZQJMH</RequestId>
    <HostId>pEkHWAWitW8Ay30lDuCUG3Yg8yucEyQH+ExKjaMc7OrrcIqkiK8a6/cRYNmWWXj0jIK3rFtcsbA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My bucket is in us-east-1 region. Here is my code generating pre-signed URL:

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("us-east-1")
            .build();

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, objectKey)
       .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
       .withExpiration(getExpirationDate());
URL url = amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Comment: The error seems rather clear, you're specifying us-east-1 for a bucket in the ca-central-1 region

Comment: But my bucket is in us-east-1 region

Comment: AWS doesn't think so

Comment: How can I set it then? When I go into properties of my bucket it says us-east-1 in region

Comment: Never mind, I had a bad bucket name